# ImageMagick is not processing images, but gives no errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick

My problem is is that paperclip saves the attachments appropriately, and I assume imagemagick is doing something right. With no errors returning, the images never finish processing.

Does anyone know a way to see what's backgrounding?
Or specifically a way to review imagemagick's processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tail -f log/delayed_job.log  for "backgrounding"
And imagemagick's processes can be seen in your regular production log.
tail -f log/production.log